# HTML formatted text in Swing components dont show up

Tags: java, html, swing

I have recently came upon odd situation; HTML formatted text in my Swing components do not show up. I have searched for similar questions, and found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119157/html-in-jlabel-not-showing), but it does not seem to resolve in a solution that applies to my case (even though there is an accepted answer)

I have also played around with the `HtmlDemo` class on the [Oracle tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html). The code copied from there to my project does not work, the same way as my own code doesn't. However if I compile the whole project, or run it via JWS, everything looks OK.

I have tried to isolate the problem with smaller cases (such as the commented `JLabel`s) but still no joy. Currently I am really puzzled; almost certain that I miss a detail somewhere but can't seem to locate it.

Below is a method that returns a `JScrollPane` to be placed in a `JTabbedPane`, which should depict the relevant pieces of the code. Oh, and btw I am currently using Sun JDK 1.6.0 `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)`

Any help/comments are appreciated!

---

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(); 

JComponent panel1 = makeInfoPanel(v);
tabbedPane.addTab("Node Info", null, panel1,"info");
tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

JComponent panel2 = makeDetailsPanel(v);
tabbedPane.addTab("Details", null, panel2,"other info");
tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);
```

---

```
protected JComponent makeInfoPanel(Node v) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,200));
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

    //JLabel title = new JLabel("<html><b><u>T</u>wo</b><br>lines</html>");
    String msg = "Below are the items this node represents";
    //JLabel title = new JLabel("<html><font size=-2>" + msg +"</font></html>");
    JLabel title = new JLabel(msg);
    title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
    panel.add(title);

    JLabel stuff = new JLabel();
    StringBuilder labelText = new StringBuilder("<html><h3>Items</h3>");
    for(Stuff s : v.getStuff()){
        labelText.append("<font size=8><i>" + s.getName() + "</i></font>");
        labelText.append("&nbsp;nbsp;&nbsp; <font size=6>" + s.getDb().toUpperCase() + "</font>");
        labelText.append("<br>");
    }

    labelText.append("</html>");
    stuff.setText(labelText.toString());

    panel.add(stuff);

    return new JScrollPane(panel);
}
```

Comment: What are `Stuff` and `Node v` ??

Comment: @Favonius: They are two custom classes, I have a tree-like hierarchy which consists of `Node`s, where every node refers to a number of things, such as `Stuff`. What I am trying to do is to add contextual info boxes that pop-up upon clicking a node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the fix shown at the bottom of [Bug ID 7008526](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7008526).

This is how I implement the fix in an applet that uses HTML rendering.

```
public void init() {
    // Solves an applet/HTML parsing bug.
    ParserDelegator parserDelegator = new ParserDelegator();
    System.out.println("parserDelegator set: "+ parserDelegator);
```

By creating an explicit parser delegator and storing a reference to it, it is never *recreated* and so does not trigger the error.

Comment: Can you say, what the fix was? The bug, in which the fix seems to be stored is not accessible anymore (http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6990651) . Thank you!