# What stops my data from being displayed in a Jframe when i use HTML code in added JLabel?

Tags: java, html, swing

I use a line of code exactly like this one:

```
    MyFrame.add(new JLabel("<html><body>Information to be displayed</body></html>"));
```

Each time i execute my project, nothing displays in the JFrame MyFrame including other data not related to the JLabel. Please someone should kindly tell me where i'm going wrong.

Comment: (1-) `Please someone should kindly tell me where i'm going wrong.` - how can we possible know what you are doing wrong based on a single line of code. `nothing displays in the JFrame MyFrame including other data not related to the JLabel.` - so then the HTML is not the problem. Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for working examples. Download the demo code and change the labels in the demo code to use HTML.

Comment: Thank you for that link.  I was able to learn new methods of using html.  Will try to apply them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's duplicate question, see: 
[How do I put html in a JLabel in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635730/how-do-i-put-html-in-a-jlabel-in-java) 
[HTML in JLabel not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119157/html-in-jlabel-not-showing)

test this code:

```
    JFrame MyFrame=new JFrame();
    MyFrame.setSize(300, 300);
    MyFrame.add(new JLabel("<html><font color='green'>Information to be </font> displayed <br/>it is tested</html>"));
    MyFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry about my mistake

Comment: None of those really works.  Is there any Java method that is not compatible with html in a Jframe? I just think that it may be possible I've used one.